# Добавить текст из textarea в переменную

Tags: javascript, textarea

Как добавить содержимое поля `<textarea></textarea>` в переменную через Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте вашему элементу textarea id и получите значение элемента через id.

```
var text = document.getElementById('textareaId').value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var vari = textarea.value;
console.log(vari);
textarea.oninput = function() {
  vari = this.value;
  console.log(vari);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">Этот текст должен быть в переменной</textarea>
```